# How can I parse html using lxml , python

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I have some html file:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <span class="text">One</span>some text1</br>
   <span class="cyrillic">Мир</span>some text2</br>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can i get "some text1" and "some text2" using lxml with python?

Comment: Here's the tutorial: http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html
Anything specific you don't understand?

Comment: This tutorial link is defunct. Please remove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring("""<html>
 <body>
   <span class="text">One</span>some text1</br>
   <span class="cyrillic">Мир</span>some text2</br>
 </body>
</html>
""")

txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/span[@class="text"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')
txt2 = doc.xpath('/html/body/span[@class="cyrillic"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')
```

Answer (score 3):

I use lxml for xml parsing, but I use BeautifulSoup for HTML. Here's a very quick/brief tour, ending with one solution to your question. Hope it helps.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79359, Mar 24 2010, 01:32:55) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as soup
>>> stream = open('bs.html', 'r')
>>> doc = soup(stream.read())
>>> doc.body.span
<span class="text">One</span>
>>> doc.body.span.nextSibling
u'some text1'
>>> x = doc.findAll('span')
>>> for i in x:
...     print unicode(i)
... 
<span class="text">One</span>
<span class="cyrillic">Мир</span>
>>> x = doc('span')
>>> type(x)
<class 'BeautifulSoup.ResultSet'>
>>> for i in x:
...     print unicode(i)
... 
<span class="text">One</span>
<span class="cyrillic">Мир</span>
>>> for i in x:
...     print i.nextSibling
... 
some text1
some text2
>>>
```